# Quiz modules doubts in drupal

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

I had installed Quiz module in Drupal. In that case,If I choose Match the following quiz the first question gets four answer option, *but the remaining questions also gets the four options.*

**What i need:** I want to display like first question should get four options,second question should get three option,like wise the last question should get one option.Can anybody guide me how to display it?